# CodeIgniter Php Raja Ongkir api get cost error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Error : 
**" A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice  Message: Undefined index: results  Filename: controllers/pengiriman.php  Line Number: 120 "**
How i can fix this..
i use code igniter 2 . and i want to create shipping method using Raja Ongkir API but the 
[**this my error image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMVpo.png)
this my code controller :

```
    public function getcost()
{
    $asal = 305;
    $dest = $this->input->post('dest', TRUE);
    $kurir = $this->input->post('kurir', TRUE);
    $berat = 0;

    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $key) {
        $berat += ($key['weight'] * $key['qty']);
    }

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/cost",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "origin=$asal&destination=$dest&weight=$berat&courier=$kurir",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "key: $this->api_key"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      $data = json_decode($response, TRUE);

      echo '<option value="" selected disabled>Layanan yang tersedia</option>';

      for ($i=0; $i < count($data['rajaongkir']['results']); $i++) {

            for ($l=0; $l < count($data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs']); $l++) {

                echo '<option value="'.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['cost'][0]['value'].','.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['service'].'('.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['description'].')">';
                echo $data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['service'].'('.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['description'].')</option>';

            }

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ca you add to your question the results of a var_dump($data); after you set $data = json_decode(...);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for the returned result status code by setting up a condition :

```
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $data = json_decode($response, TRUE);

    echo '<option value="" selected disabled>Layanan yang tersedia</option>';

    // check for return status code
    if ($data['rajaongkir']['status']['code'] == 200) {
        for ($i=0; $i < count($data['rajaongkir']['results']); $i++) {

            for ($l=0; $l < count($data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs']); $l++) {

                echo '<option value="'.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['cost'][0]['value'].','.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['service'].'('.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['description'].')">';
                echo $data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['service'].'('.$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$i]['costs'][$l]['description'].')</option>';

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://rajaongkir.com/dokumentasi/starter#cost-response) example it's provide `'200'` (for success response) and `'400'` (for error response) status code.
Furthermore, you could improve it by only showing the cost option when there are cost data to show, so it will not show empty cost data when errors happened..